# Could not able to get filePath using Nsfilemanager in Custom FrameWork

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit, xcode-6.2

I'm working on Apple Watch application, so I have created one custom framework. Currently I'm trying to fetch data from a static JSON file. The JSON file is in my application bundle, but I couldn't parse data from that `.json` file.

> Note: I'm trying to fetch data in custom framework class, my code is here:

```
NSString *jsonFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test_json_PCC" ofType:@"json" inDirectory:nil];
    NSData *data;
    if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:jsonFile])
    {
        data = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:jsonFile];
    }
        else
    {
        NSLog(@"File not exits");
    }
```

I am always getting "File not exits" errors in the console.

Answer (score 0):

try this ....with that u can access the file from your main bundle without using NSFileManager...

```
NSString *Path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"begArray" ofType:@"json"];

contents = [NSMutableString stringWithContentsOfFile:Path
                                                encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                   error:NULL];//contents is a NSMutableString to store your file data...
```

Comment: xcode always find the correct file if you gives the correct file name and extension.

Comment: you please give your json file name to the path resource...because i made a mistake in editing ....